# Can I patent code that is pushed to Github?

Tags: prior-art, software, public, patenting-an-algorithm

I have invented a new algorithm that I want to patent in Germany/Europe. However, I have kept my code implementing the algorithm in a public GitHub repository. I have not assigned a copyright license to it. The question is, can I patent this algorithm now? or does keeping it in a public repository invalidate any patent applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are applying in Europe via the EPO you have to contend with their definition of “made available to the public.” In section G IV we find

> 6.4
> Internet disclosures
> As a matter of principle, disclosures on the internet form part of the prior art. Information disclosed on the internet or in online databases is considered to be publicly available as of the *date the information was publicly posted*.

Comment: Thanks, that is really clear.

Answer (score 1):

In general code itself is protected by copyright not patents. However, you may potentially get a patent on an algorithm as applied to specific task or problem. The mathematical algorithm by itself will almost assuredly be considered abstract and thus unpatentable. My understanding is that algorithm based patents are hard to obtain in Europe, but I'm not an expert.

By publishing your code, you make it prior art and thus your algorithm is unpatentable. In the US there is a 12 month grace period so depending on when you uploaded it to Github you might still be able to pursue a patent there. It's possible if you delete the Github repository it might not be discovered by the patent office, but you are probably out of luck.

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. It would be best to consult with an actual patent attorney.

Comment: If a person is accused of murder they can tell their lawyer they did it and the lawyer can’t tell anyone. If the same person wants to hide a relevant fact about their invention being available on GitHub and tells their patent practitioner, the patent practitioner is required to tell the USPTO.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I wasn’t suggesting it was a legitimate thing to do. That said, some random GitHub repository may well have never been visited by anyone other than the owner. If GitHub has tools to confirm that, it might be somewhat more ethical to remove the repository.

Comment: Nothing wrong with removing it as long as it is all disclosed. If you disclosed on an IDS that the material was theoretically available to the public you would avoid inequitable conduct and would have complied with the duty of candor and disclosure to the USPTO. You might be able to establish that it was never actually acceded. However there are famous cases where something was available to the public but proven to not ever have been accessed by anyone in the public and where the inventors lost out. One regarding a stay in the inventor’s fiancées garment and one involving a car part.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That is really helpful. Perhaps you might add an answer. Is that also true in Europe where the OP wants to patent?

Comment: Yes my comment was a US comment. Most places have no duty to disclose or have anything like an IDS but I’ll think about a more full answer

Comment: Ah, thank you for the answer; So, if my understanding is correct, there is nothing equivalent to the grace period in Europe and Germany? Is there any relevant documentation I could check out?

Comment: @rahul My understanding is that there is no similar grace period in Europe, but that might depend on individual countries. However if you only have the algorithm on GitHub and not the specific application, there might be some patentability. I'd delete the repository and consult with an actual patent attorney familiar with algorithm patents.

Comment: @rahul My understanding is that GitHub allows you to monitor visitation to the repository. If no one has actually visited the repository, you might be able to consider it unpublished at least ethically if not legally.

Comment: See EPO rules G IV 6.4
Internet disclosures 
As a matter of principle, disclosures on the internet form part of the prior art. Information disclosed on the internet or in online databases is considered to be publicly available as of the date the information was publicly posted.